# Pay Pal Recurring payments via direct payments

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have some problems with integration of Recurring Payments with PayPal.
I developed Recurring Payments via Direct Payment with "Payment Pro" API. 
It works fine on "Sandbox" environment but when we switch to "Live" we get error "DPRP is not enabled for this merchant". 
Is PayPal doesn't support "Payment Pro" API?
If PayPal still supports "Payment Pro" API, please tell me which features must be enabled in merchant account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error says, it's not enabled for your account. You will need to sign up for PayPal Website Payments Pro and request them to add the Direct Recurring Payments product to your account.